# Can not communicate CS9 in ROS with staubli_val3_driver package

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-melodic, robotic-arm, driver

I am trying to implement a Staubli TX2-140 arm in ROS using staubli_val3_driver. I have copied val3 folder to the controller. When I open ros_server VAL3 app in teach pendant I have the following error log:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this or has anyone managed to communicate a CS9 controller with ROS?